# Filter or find on another array vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

There are two arrays, I receive data from the backend.
In the first array of the city, in the second, delivery time.

First:

```
region: {
 type: Array,
 default: () => []
},
```

Second:

```
deliveryTime:  {
 type: Array,
 default: () => []
}
```

come as a regular array, key-value. (for example-- `Region: [{"name": "Boston"}, {"name":"Detroit"}, {""}];` and DeliveryTime: `[{"name": "Detroit","delivery_time: "2-7""},{"name": "Boston","delivery_time": "1-3"},{"}]`)
If the names are the same, I need to output delivery time.

I tried:

```
<div v-for='(reg, index) in deliveryTime' :key='index' > 
  <span :class='{ "reg": findTime(reg) }'> {{ reg }} </span>
</div>
///////////////
findTime(reg) {
  return this.region.includes(reg);
}
```

Finds matching cities, but how to refer to `delivery_time`

Comment: From your question im not sure what you want exactly. Your function findTime just returns a boolean. If you want to display the deliveryTime you could use
{{ reg.delivery_time }}

Comment: @Flashtube If used ```{{ reg.delivery_time }}``` it displays all delivery values, not the city that is selected :c

Answer (score 2):

Both array elements contain the region name in the `name` property, so `findTime()` needs to read that property from `this.region[]` and from `reg` (i.e., the `deliveryTime[]` array element).

Use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to compare each region's `name` to the delivery time's region:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    findTime(reg) {
      return this.region.some(r => r.name === reg.name)
    }
  }
}
```

Then to conditionally display the item, use [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) in your template:

```html
<span v-if="findTime(reg)">{{ reg.name }}</span>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-filtering-data?file=src/components/DeliveryTimes.vue)

Another way to solve the problem is to compute the filtered results:

```html
<template>
  <div v-for='(reg, index) in computedDeliveryTime'>
    <span> {{ reg.name }} </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    computedDeliveryTime() {
      return this.deliveryTime.filter(d => {
        return this.region.some(r => r.name === d.name)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-filtering-data-2azee3?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FDeliveryTimes.vue)